# Source for zugos arguments

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, amoroim

Is there any sefer that collects the various arguments of each zug (study pair)? Such as all the arguments of R yochanan and reish lukish, or abye and rava. It would be nice if it also proposed some sort of theory as to each amoras general theories which explains the individual arguments (like a לשיטתן, i.e. where seemingly disparate discussions revolve around a single idea).

Comment: Didn't R' Reuven Margolies do this?

Comment: @mroll Is there any example of this one could see in, like, English?

Comment: @SAH beis Hillel (B"H)  and beis shamay (B"S). By chanuka do you start with 8 and go down or or with and go up. B"H says start with 1 and go up. B"S says start with 8 and go down. In general B"H is more lenient and B"S is more strict. B"H looks at how things practically are. There has been x amount of days, people will do z. B"S looks at potential. There still could be x amount of days of chanuka, people are capable of z. This is based off my memory, don't have the source in front of me so I'm pretty sure I'm wrong in the details but thats the idea.

Comment: @mroll Thanks. A pity the rest of the comments were deleted.